# read binary file, translate bytes in base16, format, write back in an ascii file

Tags: c++, std, iostream

Using the following code, I read an executable file and I create a file that will be used to store a variable, a simple `C char array`.

```
    ifstream fIn( argv[1], ios::binary );
    if( !fIn.is_open() )
        throw (exception("Could not open file."));

    ofstream fOut( argv[2] );
    if( !fOut.is_open() )
        throw (exception("Could not create file."));

    // def of the C array
    // name of the variable which will be write in the new file
    fOut << "unsigned char " << varName << "[] =\n{"; // varName = "foobar";

    stringstream ss;
    string s;
    static char c = 0;
    // copy each byte in 's'
    while(fIn.get(c)) s += c;
    // generate the file
    fOut <<  for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), hexify<char>(ss));
    // end of def
    fOut << "\n};\n";
```

The `hexify<T> struct` body and `operator<<` used to satisfy my formating needs

```
    template<typename T> struct hexify 
    {
        hexify(stringstream& out) : _ss(out), _n(0) {}
        void operator() (T& x) 
        { 
            if(  _n > 0 )        _ss << ", ";
            if( (_n % 16) == 0 ) _ss << "\n\t";
                _ss << "0x" << setbase(16) << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (unsigned int)x;
            _n++;
        }
        stringstream& _ss;
        int _n;
    };

    template<typename T>
    ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const hexify<T>& h ) { os << h._ss.str(); return os; }
```

-

For this situation let me say I read only **the first 4 bytes** of the file and save thoses bytes in a `char` array `foobar[]` :

> 4d5a 9000 0300 0000 0400 0000 ffff 0000

The result I expect for the `foobar array` definition *(in the previoulsy created file)* should be :

```
 unsigned char foobar[] = { 0x4d, 0x5a, 0x90, 0x00 };
```

The result I obtain myself :

```
 unsigned char foobar[] = { 0x4d, 0x5a, 0xffffff90, 0x00 };
```

**Why the third byte is wrapped with 'f' ?**

Another example with 112 bytes :

```
   unsigned char foobar[] =
   {
        0x4d, 0x5a, 0xffffff90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0xffffffb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfffffff0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0x0e, 0x1f, 0xffffffba, 0x0e, 0x00, 0xffffffb4, 0x09, 0xffffffcd, 0x21, 0xffffffb8, 0x01, 0x4c, 0xffffffcd, 0x21, 0x54, 0x68, 
        0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x67, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x20, 0x63, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x6e, 0x6f, 
        0x74, 0x20, 0x62, 0x65, 0x20, 0x72, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x44, 0x4f, 0x53, 0x20
   };
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using the [std::hex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) I/O stream manipulator, instead of rolling your own?

Comment: using `_ss << "0x" << std::hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (unsigned int)x;` give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A char is not the same data type as an unsigned int.  I think your cast is sign-extending the upper bit of your char ( which is 1) and filling the remaining 24 bits of an unsigned int. This is kludgey, but try masking off the upper bits. I tried this after/before:

```
char y = 0x90;
 cout << "0x" << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (unsigned int)(y&0xFF) << endl;
 cout << "0x" << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (unsigned int)y << endl;
```

and got this output:

[image]

The other option is to properly change your data type to an unsigned char also.  Your template call currently has it as a char, not unsigned char. That will also work w/o the masking.

Comment: thanks to pointing it out. I see what's my error.  But dont see the point of the community about the downvote.

Comment: I agree.  Some people are just jerks.  You provided all the relevant information, and it was an interesting problem.